# Reciprocity Theorems in Physics

Tags: electromagnetism, fluid-dynamics, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance

So far I have come across [reciprocity theorems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reciprocity_theorem) in electrostatics (relating the potential and charge distributions; Griffiths) and fluid dynamics (relating the flow fields and boundary forces; Pozrikidis). It is fascinating how you can relate two non-interacting objects and their corresponding effect on the medium in this fashion. There seem to be a few other areas that have similar theorems; structural engineering and electrical engineering are two examples.

What is special about this theorem that it keeps popping up in so many unrelated areas? Is this just a mathematical trick or is there some deeper physics underlying it?